# What are the limitations of Windows CE 4.2?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce, activesync

Other than Active Sync not working, are there any other limitations that I need to consider when targeting a Windows CE 4.2 device for a CF 3.5 application in C# that uses WCF to talk to a server?

Comment: Wait, how did you get CF 3.5 on Windows CE 4.2? I can't even install .NET CF 2.0 on my CE 4.2 devices.

Comment: I asked the question because a client wanted to get a used CE device. Luckily, he changed his mind and got a WM 5 device instead, so I never actually had to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your target machine. If you have limited storage resource (ROM, flash disk?) you must consider the system image size, since CF adds some megabytes to your binary. I had to remove some componets to gain about 1 Mb on my (quite small) ARM-based target.